Let A be the 2×2 integral matrix Determine for which positive integers n, there is a complex matrix B such that B^n = A.
Let $A$ be the 2×2 integral matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    -4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
Determine for which positive integers $n,$ there is a complex matrix B such that $B^n = A$.
Here are my approaches.

Assume the matrix $B$ has the following form.

\begin{pmatrix}
    Z_1 & Z_2\\
    Z_3 & Z_4\\
\end{pmatrix}
where $Z_1,Z_2$ are complex numbers. Hence,
$det(B)^n=detA$, then since the determinant is multiplicative,
$(det(B))^n=9$
$(Z_1Z_4-Z_2Z_3)^n=9$
For the moment I assumed $n=2$ and then yielded the following complex polynomial
$(Z_1Z_4-Z_2Z_3)^2=9$
I was trying to guess some complex numbers but no luck.

The second approach was to diagonalize the matrix $A$ and try to write $B^n=P^{-1}DP$. But it turned out that $A$ has repetitive eigen values and is not diagonalizable.

Could you tell me if I'm on the right track or If I'm missing something?
Thanks

Multiple eigenvalues does not automatically imply that it is not diagonalizable.

All complex invertible matrices have $n$-th roots.

Let's look at this problem in general. Let $A$ be an arbitrary $2\times 2$ complex matrix.
If $A$ is diagonalizable, then there exist multiple matrices $B$ that work for any $n\gt 1$. Find invertible $P$ such that
$$PAP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{array}\right),$$
and let $\mu_i$ be an $n$th complex root of $\lambda_i$. Then letting
$$B = P^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\mu_1 & 0\\
0 & \mu_2
\end{array}\right)P$$
will do.
If $A$ is not diagonalizable, then there exists an invertible complex matrix $P$ and a complex number $\lambda$ such that
$$PAP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda
\end{array}\right).$$
Note that
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & a
\end{array}\right)^n = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a^n & nba^{n-1}\\
0 & a^n
\end{array}\right),$$
If $\lambda\neq 0$, then let $\mu$ be a complex $n$th root of $\lambda$, and let $b=\frac{1}{n\lambda^{n-1}}$. Then letting
$$C = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\mu & b\\
0 & \mu
\end{array}\right)$$
gives $C^n = PAP^{-1}$, so letting $B=P^{-1}CP$ will do.
Finally, if $\lambda = 0$, then there is no matrix $B$ such that $B^n=PAP^{-1}$ if $n\geq 2$. If such a $B$ existed, then we would have $B^{2n} = PA^2P^{-1} = \mathbf{0}_{2\times 2}$; then the minimal polynomial of $B$ divides $x^{2n}$, and has degree at most two, so it equals either $x$ or $x^2$. Either way, $B^2=\mathbf{0}_{2\times 2}$, so $B^n=\mathbf{0}_{2\times 2}\neq PAP^{-1}$.
Note. For $n=2$, this can be done "by hand" (without relying on the minimal polynomial) as follows: letting
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right),$$
we would have
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a^2+bc & ab+bd\\
ac + cd & bc+d^2
\end{array}\right).$$
This would require
$$\begin{align*}
a^2+bc &= 0\\
b(a+d) &=1\\
c(a+d) &=0\\
bc+d^2 &= 0
\end{align*}.$$
From the second and third equations we see that $a+d\neq 0$ and hence $c=0$. This means that $a=0$ (from the first equation), and $d=0$ (from the fourth equation), which makes the second equation impossible.
So $A$ has a complex $2\times 2$ matrix $n$th root, $n\geq 2$, if and only if $A$ is not non-diagonalizable with repeated eigenvalue $0$.
Your particular matrix $A$ has determinant $9$, which means it is invertible, and hence does not fall under the exception. Thus, it always has $n$th roots.
